# How to add a control in order to pass collection elements to another collection in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I need to add a control to the UI in order to have the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M9Q5.png)

How can I achieve that?

I tried to find it in the documentation but I wasn't able to.
Can anyone tell me where I can find that control please?

Comment: You’ll have to build it yourself

Comment: There is no such control in maui. It's a custom control which combines ListView/CollectionView, button,label and so on.